# Difficulty in pinpointing potential PhD supervisor's current interest from their publications

Tags: phd, supervision

I want to pursue a PhD in experimental particle physics and am looking for a supervisor. I know that the first advice to students like me is to go through the professor's most recent paper. However, the journals in my field are usually published collaboratively, which means the number of authors ranges from tens to thousands per paper.
For example, [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168900222006945?via%3Dihub) has 29 authors and [this](https://inspirehep.net/literature/2045484) has 1030 of them.
Therefore, it is difficult for me to identify what the professor has been interested in recently. Sometimes I am lucky enough to find the topics of their past supervised students, but I am not sure if I can go through those theses and ask them questions based on those topics. To make matters worse, some do not update their research interest or the topics of the past supervised projects, and I am not sure if it is appropriate to write to them and ask them what they do.

Any suggestions for the situations mentioned above?

Comment: Hmmm, when you search by author, does it not provide you with a list of their research interests even if they typically co-author with lots of other people? Even for huge LHC collabs, different groups still publish whitepapers and present at conferences about their bits of work there, and HEP communities are very open about sharing the information. Papers authored by those potential supervisors do not have to all be in Phys. Rev. D or something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some other possible ways to determine a professor's research interests are:

- Check to see if he/she has presented at conferences lately. That might have a more reduced author list.
- This might be futile if all the publications have 1000s of authors, but you can always check Google scholar. Sort by citation count, then see if you can find some recent papers that have a fewer number of authors.
- You can ask your professors at your current institution; they might know the professor you want to work with.
- You can check the professor's website (although websites are notoriously out of date!)
- You can google search for press releases featuring the faculty member. If they have won large grants - and you probably don't want to work with someone who hasn't - they will often be featured by the institution's internal press.
- You can email the professor's graduate students. (Talking to current and recent grad students is a good idea regardless.)

I would not recommend emailing the professor to ask what their research interests are. That is almost certainly going to be poorly received - faculty get lots of emails from prospective students, and they expect the students to have done their homework.

Good luck!

Comment: Inspire-HEP is probably more useful in this specific case than Google Scholar.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestions from the other answers, here are a few ideas in no particular order:

- Check their faculty web page. It may be out of date, but could give you a sense of what they have worked on in the past. If there is a CV on their web page, they are likely to only include the papers that they were directly involved in even if they are on the author list for the entire collaboration.
- Ask other members of their collaboration. HEP-Ex collaborations can be gigantic, but usually people has some sense of what others in the collaboration are working on.
- Ask senior academics in the field who you know. People pick up a large network over time and it's not that large of a field.
- If you think the professor is heavily involved in a particular paper, look for them or their students or post-docs as corresponding authors on the paper. There may also be a contribution list in the paper.
- Big collaborations are often broken into working groups. See if the person has a leadership role in a working group. This might not be publicly available information but sometimes people advertise it.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to a librarian (research librarian) at your university or a nearby one. Write to a librarian at the person's institution. They are very good about such things.

Their "most recent" paper(s) may not be required, or even very helpful, actually. If you have a grasp on their (fairly) recent work and interests then it may be enough.

You could also ask them directly for references to recent works, saying you are interested in the same things and are looking for a doctoral supervisor, without directly asking them to be that person. A first communication of that form might actually be helpful. The might even have suggestions about others you might want to approach.

Comment: I am absolutely sure that the librarian at my institution has no idea who I am, much less what I am interested in working on.

Answer (score 0):

[Sarcastic joke about the social reticence of profs removed after some reflection, and a nice high-calorie lunch. Apologies.]

But seriously. You have the name of a potential prof. He knows the author list on those papers. Google up his home university, see if you can find his email, and send him a nice email. Ask him what his current research program includes, and whether your interests might be a match.

You should state near the top of your email that you are interested in being a PhD student, that you are looking for a supervisor, that you are interested in X, Y, and Z. And when you would be starting, supposing you were accepted at his university.